Automatic markdown translation in convert-to-comment went awry
Hmm. Over on MathOverflow I automatically converted an answer to a comment, and the result was (at first) this (given in source markdown to show the mess):
This may be (vaguely) related to fractional coloring [(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring)(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring),(https://www.ams.jhu.edu/ers/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fgt.pdf)(https://www.ams.jhu.edu/ers/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fgt.pdf)]?
The original answer (obviously now deleted) was this:

This may be (vaguely) related to fractional coloring [1,2]?

The links were autoconverted in to garbage as can be seen. The original source was
This may be (vaguely) related to fractional coloring [[1][1],[2][2]]?


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring

  [2]: https://www.ams.jhu.edu/ers/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fgt.pdf

I can see how the script to change the answer to a comment just replaced both copies of [n] by ($url_n) each time. I guess it's such a corner case, but it's not completely unreasonable that people might make reference links like this.
I only found out that the comments was messed up when the user contacted me, because I converted to comment in response to a flag and moved on without checking the result.
Is there anything that can be sorted in the convert-to-comment feature to prevent this?

Markdown doesn't work in a comment outside of [chat] and [edit] so should it be stripped out instead ?  Let's not risk loosing this function.

@Criggie um, I think that the bits of markdown that work in comments might be more constrained, but I certainly use the basics of markdown (formatting for italics, bold, verbatim; links; MathJax/LaTeX) all the time. Who would want to put a table, a list or headings etc in a comment?

The Markdown This may be (vaguely) related to fractional coloring [[1],[2]]? would also have the same rendered output in posts, and would likely not have resulted in the glitch on comment conversion.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Sure, but that's not what the user originally wrote, and I wasn't going to check the source of the non-answer before converting it to a comment.

Looks like I was wrong - it still would have been glitched. The above Markdown in an answer produces the following in a comment: This may be (vaguely) related to fractional coloring [(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring),(https://www.ams.jhu.edu/ers/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fgt.pdf)]?

Ideally, the comment conversion script should render the answer as HTML, perform the parsing on the HTML, then convert it back to Markdown. This would avoid any glitches.

@Sonic probably a quick regex on the HTML can handle that conversion, right?
